# Wireshark to capture router MAC's

Tags: router, mac-address, wireshark

Is there any way I can capture the router IP or MAC addresses along the path of a ping packet using Wireshark tool?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin No I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer sir. Still searching.

Comment: You may not like the answer, but you simply can't is the correct answer.

Comment: Oh then if you could post that answer I can accept that as the answer sir.

Comment: That's really what my answer says, especially, the last sentence, "_The addresses of the devices in the path are not captured along the way._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only capture addresses in the headers of the network stack:

- Layer-2 source and destination addresses. The source address will be
  the address of the host on your LAN which originated the frame in your LAN. The destination address will be your address. Layer-2 addresses, e.g. MAC addresses, are only relevant or seen in the LAN where the hosts are.
- Layer-3 source and destination addresses. The source address will be
  the address of the host which originated the packet (or the address
  of a NAT device for the originating host). The destination address will be your address.
- Layer-4 source and destination addresses. The source address will be
  the port used by the originating host (or the port used by the NAT
  device of the originating host). The destination address will be the port on your host.

The addresses of the devices in the path are not captured along the way.